# Android ad request. Keywords from string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, admob

I'm trying to add each item in an array list stored in R.array.list to an adrequest for admob. When i log the adrequest i get something like "com.google.ads.AdRequest@42168310". This doesnt seem right since i used to get an actual list when outputting the request, I used to add each item in the java manually by doing:

```
adRequest.addKeyword("thisisakeyword");
```

Here is what i'm trying now:

```
keyWords = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.key_words);

    int count = 0;
    while (count < keyWords.length) {
        adRequest.addKeyword(keyWords[count]);
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(adRequest.toString()));
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Incase anyone comes across this. The trick is to add the array to a set and then add the set to the ad request.

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    String[] keywords = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.key_words);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    int count = 0;
    while (count < keywords.length) {
        set.add(keywords[count]);
        count++;
    }
    adRequest.addKeywords(set);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this while trying to do the same thing and realised that it's overly-complicated and you're creating unnecessary variables. You don't actually need to create a set or a counter.

Try this instead:

```
Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
String[] keywords = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.key_words);
for (String keyword : keywords) {
    adRequestBuilder.addKeyword(keyword);
}
```

Hope this helps.